# Perl6 getting a regex from a string

Tags: regex, raku

I want to put a regex in a YAML config file (say: config/filename.yaml), eg.

```
-
  section: Begining
  regex: '/ ^ <[ a..b, A..B ]> /'
-
  section: Next
  regex: '/ ^ <[ c..z, C..Z ]> /'
```

When I read this into a hash (eg. using YAMLish), eg.,

```
use YAMLish;
my @h = load-yaml('config/filename.yaml'.IO.slurp);
```

naturally I have a string in `@h[0]<regex>`

So how do I recover a regex from a string for use in a match?

I want something like the following, but the following doesn't work:

```
say 'Its a beginning' if 'A beginning' ~~ @h[0]<regex>
```

It doesn't work as desired because `@h[0]<regex>` is a Str, so the smart match is testing a Str in `@h[0]<regex>` against a Str literal. So how to get the regex out of the Str?

Answer (score 12):

You interpolate a string held in a variable `$var` into a regex via `/ <$var> /`, or, in case of more complex expressions like yours, `/ <{ @h[0]<regex> }> /`.

Note, however, that you first have to remove the enclosing slashes from your string. For trusted input, there's of course always `EVAL`...

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a good idea to compile external regexes, so you know right away if they fail (and they will be faster afterwards):

Perl6 REPL:

```
> my $str = '\d+'; my $rx = rx/ <$str> /; say "a" ~~ $rx; say "10" ~~ $rx
Nil
｢10｣
```

Of course it's easier providing a "pure" regex, not one that also has syntax (/ /).

[Perl documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#index-entry-quote_%2F_%2F-quote_rx-quote_m-Lexical_conventions)